# Prevent configuration properties binding in Spring test

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test

I have the following configuration class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "xyz")
@Validated
public class AppConfiguration {
    @NotNull
    private Path path;
}
```

And I'm trying to create the test configuration like that:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public AppConfiguration testConfig() {
            var configuration = new AppConfiguration();
            configuration.setPath(path);
            return configuration;
    }
}
```

The `path` points to the temporary test dir so I can't set it in property file.

This worked fine until I added @Validated to my test. Then I realised Spring first creates my test configuration bean but later it still attempts to do the biding and fails since in my test `application.yml` there is no `xyz` therefore the `path` is null and validation exception is raised.
If I add to application.yml:

```
xyz:
   path: dummy
```

This "dummy" value will override the `path` I set in test configuration.

Is there any way to tell Spring not to do the configuration properties binding during test and just use the bean from `@TestConfiguration` as is?
Or maybe there is better way to do approach this?